# NPE when calling MockitoAnnotations.initMocks() in AndroidTestCase

Tags: java, android, testing, gradle, mockito

Trying to use mockito in my AndroidTestCase. I added the dependencies to the build.gradle:

```
final DEXMAKER_VERSION = '1.2'

dependencies {
    // ...
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:${DEXMAKER_VERSION}"
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:${DEXMAKER_VERSION}"
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

}
```

The TestCase with  the mockito initialization:

```
public class UsersListPresenterTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public void testInitialize() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

But as soon as I add any attribute to the class, even before adding any annotation the test start to crash:

```
public class UsersListPresenterTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    String mockString;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public void testInitialize() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

With the following stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
    'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker.getInvocationHandlerAdapter(DexmakerMockMaker.java:80)
at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker.getHandler(DexmakerMockMaker.java:75)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.isMockitoMock(MockUtil.java:74)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.isMock(MockUtil.java:66)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.scanner.MockScanner.isMockOrSpy(MockScanner.java:86)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.scanner.MockScanner.preparedMock(MockScanner.java:72)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.scanner.MockScanner.scan(MockScanner.java:61)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.scanner.MockScanner.addPreparedMocks(MockScanner.java:47)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.injectMocks(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:96)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processInjectMocks(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:62)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:56)
at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:108)
at com.myproject.presentation.UsersListPresenterTest.setUp(UsersListPresenterTest.java:28)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to replace

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

with this

```
System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", getContext().getCacheDir().getPath());
```

It works for me. [See ref here](http://www.kevinrschultz.com/blog/2014/08/31/mockito-and-android-how-to/)

Comment: How does this play along with JUnit 4 tests? There is no `getContext` one could use.

Comment: @Matthias, you use InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().

Comment: Right, I had it figured out meanwhile. Thanks.

Comment: @danielgomezrico using -
    System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getCacheDir().getPath());

Comment: Another way: `System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", activityTestRule.getActivity().getCacheDir().getPath())`

Comment: How do you solve this problem in Junit test because `InstrumentationRegistry` is in `android.support.test`

Answer (score 6):

Its a bug in dexmaker for which I have submitted a fix:
https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker/pull/24

Comment: are they ever going to merge this in?!

Comment: Because I use modified source sets I need to install this library as a jar (it will NOT compile from gradle) so I need it in the jar :(

Comment: dshirley asked me to take over the project - I agreed, but it hasn't actually happened - so I am afraid I am powerless. If nothing happens soon I will create a fork.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to use the Method `Mockito.mock()` for each Mocking Object instead of using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

So for example:

```
public class HomePresenterTest {
    private Repository repository;
    private HomePresenter presenter;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        repository = mock(Respository.class);
        presenter = new HomePresenter(repository);
    }

    //Your tests
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created an issue there https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/392
Original answer with hotfix there https://stackoverflow.com/a/36642606/1224247