# Mockito AbstractMethodError on initMocks

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockito

So I've been struggling pretty much all day trying to get Mockito to work for my Android project.
I added everything to my Gradle build file:

```
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.29-beta'
androidTestCompile "junit:junit:4.12-beta-3"
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
```

and have tried running a test that doesn't really do anything:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginActivityTest extends 
    ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {

    private LoginActivity loginActivity;

    private EditText et_email;
    private EditText et_password;
    private Button btn_login;

    @Mock
    SpiceManager manager;

    public LoginActivityTest(){
        super(LoginActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        loginActivity = getActivity();

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        //manager = mock(SpiceManager.class);
        loginActivity.spiceManager = manager;

        et_email = (EditText) loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        et_password = (EditText) loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        btn_login = (Button) loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testLoginEmpty() throws Exception {        
        verify(manager).execute(
            any(LoginRequest.class), 
            anyString(), 
            anyLong(), 
            any(LoginActivity.LoginRequestListener.class));
    }
}
```

The reason I want to mock the service is because I would like to keep the network part out the test.
There's no need to actually send a network request for a simple test, right?

Anyhow, the app builds but when the actual test starts running it fails (or rather crashes) with an `AbstractMethodError`:

```
Running tests
Test running started
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method     
    "org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker$TypeMockability 
    org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker.isTypeMockable(java.lang.Class)"

at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:26)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:21)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:167)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:161)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:58)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1410)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1288)
at be.sanmax.membr.activities.LoginActivityTest.setUp(LoginActivityTest.java:50)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1837)
```

This strikes me as odd since the `SpiceManager` class does not contain any `abstract` methods.
It is, however, part of some package that I didn't write (`com.octo.android.robospice`). But that shouldn't be an issue. Should it?

And if that is the issue, how could I go about factoring it out from any tests? I only want to test the working of the app, not the network connection...

Comment: Run unit tests in `tests` not `androidTest`. Try not to use annotations. Do this: `SpiceManager manager = Mockito.mock(SpiceManager.class);`

Comment: didn't know there was a difference? android studio only allows me to make either a normal package or an "androidTest" package. And if you look in the code snippet you'll see that exact line commented out because it didn't work either.

Comment: @SkinnyJ that has nothing to do this with question

Comment: @SkinnyJ not really the same error nor does that question have a solution.
BTW, I forgot to put it in the question but the error occurs at the "MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)" line.
I could go for "manual" mocking but mockito will make my life a whole lot easier.

Comment: Still haven't been able to solve this issue. I guess manual mocking is my only option here?
Or perhaps some other mocking library?

Comment: I'm having the same issue when using the Mockito.mock() call. Going back to mockito-core:2.0.17-beta works though, they changed something in version 2.0.18 that breaks (for me at least) mocking in Android.

Answer (score 16):

Dexmaker does **not** support Mockito 2.0 since the definition of `MockMaker` has changed. I suggest you use Mockito 1.10.19 but then you will run into [this NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590470/npe-when-calling-mockitoannotations-initmocks-in-androidtestcase)  for which I have submitted a [fix](https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker/pull/24).

Looks like my fix is now merged into dexmaker as of version 1.5

Comment: Can you please reference where you read that Mockito 2.0 is not supported by Dexmaker? Also, I am interested if the support is on the roadmap for later.

Comment: I did not read that it did not support it - I simply tried building dexmaker with Mockito 2.0 and it did not work for me because of API changes. I have no idea what the release schedule is, but my pull request is still languishing so I don't get the impression that dexmaker is as actively maintained as it could be.

Comment: Indeed, I was using `2.0.42-beta` when getting this error.  Switching back to `1.10.19` solved the issue for me.

Comment: I tried with mockito up to 2.0.17-beta it works well, but newer versions don't work.

Answer (score 14):

For me it helped to use newest dexmaker (and remove all other powermock/mockito dependencies):

```
    androidTestCompile 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.2.0'
```

Comment: This did work for me, but it was important to remove the other existing dependencies (like original answer mentioned).  FWIW, I couldn't find a 2.2.0 version, but used a 2.19.0 versions (and I know this is constantly changing and being updated)

Answer (score 2):

Use mockito-android instead of mockti-core for instrumentation tests.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Mockito.initAnnotations` and `@RunWith` are **incompatible** to each other. They both initialize the annotations. Try to remove one of the two. I suggested to keep the runner.

Comment: hmmm, I tried that but then it comes up with a "nullInsteadOfMockException" error where it states that "if you use @Mock annotations don't miss initMocks()". So where does that come in then?

Comment: Strange. I never use initMocks() when I have MockitoRunner as Runner.
See for reference [http://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html] 
Eventually yoy could try using Mockito without annotations (Mockito.mock)

Answer (score -1):

For me it helped switching from mockito to powermock. Downgrading mockito to 1.x gave me the null exception, updgrading to 2.x gave me the AbstractMethodError. Just include in dependencies (instead of mockito):

```
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.5"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.5"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.5"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.5"
```