# Mockito : doNothing tries to invoke the void method in Android instrumented test

Tags: java, android, mocking, mockito, void

**EDIT**

When reading the [FAQ](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ), it gave me some idea about what could possibly cause an issue here. Just to give it a try, I changed the **visibility of the stubbed method** `open()` to **public** and it was executed as expected, without any exception thrown.

I'm not sure if it's a bug or the desired behaviour of version 1.10.19.

**ORIGINAL POST**

In my Android project, I'm using [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/#how) to ease the implementation of some (instrumentation) tests. I was able to mock some non-void methods, but didn't figured out **how to properly stub a void method**.

I'm trying to test a class `House`. A `House` has an attribute of type `Door` and a method `openDoor()`. A `Door` and an attribute of type `Handle` and a method `open()`. When I invoke the `openDoor()`, I would like to check if `open()` was called, so I wrote this code:

```
@Test
public void testOpenDoorInitial() {
    Door stubbedDoor = mock(Door.class);
    doNothing().when(stubbedDoor).open();
    myHouse.setDoor(stubbedDoor); //myHouse has been initialized
    myHouse.openDoor();
    verify(stubbedDoor, times(1)).open();
}

public class House {
   Door door;
   //rest of code       
   void setDoor(Door d){
      door = d;
   }
   void openDoor(){
      // some conditions
      door.open();
   }
}

public class Door {
   Handle handle;
   //... rest of code
   void open(){
      handle.tryToUse(); //Throws NullPointException
   }
}
```

The problem is that a `NullPointerException` is thrown on line `doNothing.when(stubbedDoor).open();`, telling me that `handle` is null. [doNothing()](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doNothing()) seems to actually call `open()`, which I don't expect.

Does anyone has an idea about the source of this problem ? I'm new to Mockito, so I could have missed something obvious.

To enable Mockito in instrumentation testing, I imported the following modules.

```
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.4"
androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:1.4"
androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.4"
```

Comment: Mhh, your code works fine for me in a non-android environment.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a newer version, you are using 1.10.19. I am not sure but it seems this issue was solved after, as you can see [here](https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker/issues/18#issuecomment-154350054).
[Here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core) you can find the version list.

Comment: I was able to use Mockito, it's not related to DexMaker. I'm going to try a beta version, thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: let me know! just curiosity!

Comment: Well, I changed the stubbed method visibility to 'public' and solved the issue.

Comment: ah!! it is true only public methods can be stubbed

Comment: I find it weird though ... I read about Mockoti not being able to stub private methods, but nothing abour package-access limited methods. https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mockito-And-Private-Methods

Comment: I think static methods can not be mocked too

Answer (score 2):

This may be related to Mockito's [issue 212](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mockito/issues/212), in which package-private parent classes can cause mocks to fail because Mockito couldn't stub the hidden methods. (This may be related to [synthetic methods](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073578/java-s-synthetic-methods.html) that the compiler introduces to work around visibility complications in the class hierarchy.)

Mockito 2.0 solves this problem by [switching from CGLIB to ByteBuddy](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/171); I don't remember whether ByteBuddy was a part of any 1.x release. However, you're using Mockito with DexMaker instead, which may have a similar problem.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the info. Indeed it seems that method visibility at least affects Mockito's behaviour. After other tests, it seems that class visibility also affects Mockito.

Note that the class has no parent ;) I will try Mockito 2.x when it comes out of beta, but for now I will stick to version 1.10.19. I guess that DexMaker doesn't simplify Mockito's job in that matter and may also be a potential source of issues.

Comment: Hey Jeff. I tried to use Mockito 2.x, but it seems difficult to integrate it in Android : ie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409458/mockito-abstractmethoderror-on-initmocks
Any piece of advice on this subject ? Do you use Mockito 2.x in Android (instrumented) tests ?

I think I'm just doing something wrong and should in fact write unit tests.

Comment: @Gordak Switching to Mockito 2.0 beta won't help, because the change that helped—even though the problem is solved in ByteBuddy, it's not solved in the Android code-generation library DexMaker (which Mockito has to use in instrumentation tests instead of CGLIB or ByteBuddy, because Android requires `dex` files and not `class` files). I bring up issue 212 not because it's an exact match, but only because it's evidence that _in some code-generation libraries restricted visibility can cause surprising and poorly-explained failures to mock_.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So I'll just write unit tests, where I don't need any translation from class to dex format. I guess I should have done that from the very beginning. #NewbieProgramming