# Kotlin + MockIto + Android Instrumentation Test

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

I am trying to run an `Instrumentation` test `(androidTest)` using `Mockito` in Android with `Kotlin`.

- I've the core library in my dependencies. `'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.3.3'`
- My project is written in `Kotlin` so I've `org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.3.3` to fix the final class issue.
- As I want to run the mocks in `Android`, I've `org.mockito:mockito-android:3.3.3` also in my dependencies.

but am getting below error while compiling the code

> More than one file was found with OS independent path
>   'mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker'

Here's a sample test code to reproduce the issue. Run this test as an Instrumentation test. `(androidTest)`.

**MainActivityTest**

```kotlin
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations

class Calculator {
    fun add(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
        return x + y
    }
}

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MainActivityTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var calculator: Calculator

    @Before
    fun before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        `when`(calculator.add(10, 10)).thenReturn(20)
        assertEquals(calculator.add(10, 10), 20)
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.theapache64.mockitosample"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.3.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:3.3.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.3.3'
}
```

Isn't it possible to run `Android instrumentation test` using `Kotlin` with `Mockito` ?

*NOTE: If you think this is a duplicate question, I've searched all over the internet. There are other issues with similar stack-trace, but my case is different.*

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and solution for me was this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41594789/2286422, - i.e. to use dexmaker library, which has dependency to Mockito.

Remove other Mockito `androidTestImplementation` dependencies and only add below one (you can find the latest version [here](https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker/releases)):

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.28.1'
```

**Note** that this solution will only work on devices with Android P or above ([official documentation](https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker#mocking-final-classes--methods)).

Then in actual test I'm using Mockito in following way:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class) // use Mockito runner to be able to use @Mock annotations
class MockitoTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var generalPref: GeneralPreferences

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        // make setup
    }

    @After
    @Throws(IOException::class) {
        // make cleanup
    }

    @Test
    fun testUser() {
        val repo: UserLocalRepository =
            UserLocalRepositoryImpl(generalPref) // generalPref is a mock
        val user = repo.getUser()
        Truth.assertThat(user).isNotNull()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used these dependencies, they worked for me

```
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3")
androidTestImplementation("com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito-inline:2.28.1")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
testImplementation("androidx.test:core:1.4.0")
testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-android:4.2.0")
testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.2.0")
testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:4.2.0")
```

Comment: You are mixing something up, I think. You can't import `testImplementation` libraries in your `androidTest`