# MockitoAnnotations.initMocks crash while mock() succeeds

Tags: android, mockito

I'm having troubles using @Mock annotation with my instrumentation test.

Here's my gradle dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
```

Here's a sample piece of code:

```
@Mock View mockView

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotation.initMocks(this);
    ...
}
```

This crashes with

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker.getInvocationHandlerAdapter(DexmakerMockMaker.java:80)
at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker.getHandler(DexmakerMockMaker.java:75)
...
```

However, this works

```
View mockView

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockView = Mockito.mock(View.class);
    ...
}
```

Anyone has any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Could you post the rest of the stack trace please?

Answer (score 3):

Its a bug in dexmaker. I have submitted a pull request to fix:
https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker/pull/24

Note that you may be able to work around it by avoiding null member variables in your test class.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an issue there
https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/392

really bad hotfix:

```js
try {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
  //waiting for fix
}
```