# how to mock with mockito

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking

I have a method in my `MainActivity` (Android) and I want to mock the `A` instance :

```
public void some_method() {
    A a = new A(); 
    ....   
}
```

so I created a kind of factory class as such

```
public class SomeFactory(){

 // some constructor
public A populateWithParameter(Parameter parameter){
 return new A(parameter)
} 
}
```

and the method above turns into

```
public void some_method(SomeFactory someFactory) {
        A a = someFactory.populateWithParameter(parameter); 
        a.method_call()        
        ....   
    }
```

I tried this

```
@Mock
    SomeFactory someFactory;

public void testSomeMethod() throws Exception {
        SomeFactory someFactory = new SomeFactory();
        when(someFactory.populateWithParameter(
                some_parameter)).thenReturn(null);

        mainActivity.some_method(someFactory);
...
    }
```

but I get this error message

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not mocking your factory. Also, wrong method call.

Do this instead.

```
    SomeFactory someFactory = mock(SomeFactory.class)
    when(someFactory.populateWithParameter(
            some_parameter)).thenReturn(null);

    mainActivity.some_method(someFactory);
```

**UPDATE**

Your code has changed so for completeness this is what your test should look like. In the updated code above, you were overwriting your `mock` with a real object. Assuming your objects are correctly set up. Notice the different syntax for providing a return object. I think this is more readable.

```
@Mock SomeFactory mockFactory;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); // set up annotated mocks
}

@Test
public void testSomeMethod() {
    A subject = new A();
    doReturn(subject).when(mockFactory)
                        .populateWithParameter(any(Parameter.class));
    main_activity.some_method(mockFactory);
    verify(mockFactory,times(1)).populateWithParameter(any(Parameter.class));
}
```

*Best Practices*

- When naming methods and variables, use camelCase. So `main_activity` becomes `MainActivity`, `some_method` becomes `SomeMethod`.

Comment: thank you so much for your response. In fact, I put `thenReturn(null)` just to make it simple but I need something like `thenReturn(new A)`. So, when I do that l get an issue because after creating the object `A a`, there is a method call `a.method_call()`, but then I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method "some.package.method_call"  on a null object reference`. Do you have an idea how to fix that ?

Comment: So in your A class there is a call to method_call? I would need to see that code too.

Comment: sorry I had some problem editing my post. It is now correct

Comment: thanks for your response: now I get this message `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker.getInvocationHandlerAdapter`

Comment: I found on this post a workaround for my issue `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590470/npe-when-calling-mockitoannotations-initmocks-in-androidtestcase`. But then, I get `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'my.package.A  my.factory.populateWithParameter(Parameter )' on a null object reference`

Comment: Make sure you include `com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:{mockito version number}` in your `build.gradle` file. Obviously replace `{mockito version number}` with the version number you are using to include `mockito`. If you're doing android tests its `androidTestCompile` and java its `testCompile`

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to overwrite the instance of `A` from your test. Typically this is done using an injection framework. For a simple case, you can make the field under test `protected` (assuming the test class is in the same package as the class under test).

The error you are seeing comes interacting with a "real" object as if it was a mock.

In this case `SomeFactory` is a real object so it cannot be `when()ed`

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of response of @DiscoS2, there is indeed an issue with this declaration

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

You should use instead `SomeFactory someFactory = mock(SomeFactory.class)` and then follow the updated response of @DiscoS2